# convert string to JSON object throws Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json

i am trying to convert a string with escape characters to JSON but get error

```
  var str = '[{"name":"content","readonly":false,"value":"<div class=\"blueheading\"><h2>Free Gifts for Him</h2><h3><a href=\"http://abcd.com/free-gifts-with-purchase-for-him.aspx\">View all for Him</a></h3></div>"},{"name":"cached","readonly":true,"value":true}]';
            var myObj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: Why are you writing JSON in a string literal ? Are you really writing this string in JavaScript ?

Comment: this is coming from the server side, not really writing it literally...

Comment: In most C-based languages, you'd have the same problem of having to escape the \, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have `\"` in a string literal, you have to escape the `\` : `'\\"'`.

This gives :

```
var str = '[{"name":"content","readonly":false,"value":"<div class=\\"blueheading\\"><h2>Free Gifts for Him</h2><h3><a href=\\"http://abcd.com/free-gifts-with-purchase-for-him.aspx\\">View all for Him</a></h3></div>"},{"name":"cached","readonly":true,"value":true}]';
var myObj = JSON.parse(str);
```

[Read more about special characters in string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings)